# WEB SQL Not Working With Cordova Local App

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, web-sql

I'm using cordova 2.9.0 I'm trying to use web sql with cordova. My pages load as file:///
I'm getting Dom SECURITY ERROR some times Quota Eceeds Error. Tested with Jelly Beans and ICS Android. Nothing Seems to be Working. Should I have to do any configurations to exceed quota with Cordova web view. I included all the permissions in Manifest Android

database = window.openDatabase("AgendyDb", "1.0", "Agency DB Des", 1024);

tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE AGENCY(ID Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Agency varchar(255) NOT NULL,MessageType varchar(255),Recipient varchar(255),Alert varchar(255),Username varchar(255),Email varchar(255));");

Can Someone let me know what's wrong with cordova ? Plz help

Answer (score 0):

```
database = window.openDatabase("AgendyDb", "1.0", "Agency DB Des", 1024);

database.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AGENCY (ID Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Agency varchar(255) NOT NULL,MessageType varchar(255),Recipient varchar(255),Alert varchar(255),Username varchar(255),Email varchar(255))");
});
```

Comment: I'm Using database.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AGENCY (ID Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Agency varchar(255) NOT NULL,MessageType varchar(255),Recipient varchar(255),Alert varchar(255),Username varchar(255),Email varchar(255))");
}); But Issue is da same